# How to customise PHP MYSQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I using 3 tables to store booking information: eventinfo, customer and testbook.

My Coding:

```
<?php

 include('config.php');
 $per_page = 9; 
 if($_GET)
 {
 $page=$_GET['page'];
 }

 //get table contents
 $start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
 $sql = "SELECT bookingID,eventinfo.eventTitle,boothAlias,testbook.bstatus,date'"
."testbook.username, customer.companyName, customer.contactName"
."from eventinfo, testbook, customer where testbook.username=customer.username"
." and testbook.eventID=eventinfo.eventID order by date limit $start,$per_page";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
?>


<table width="800px">

    <?php
    //Print the contents

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
    {

        $id=$row['companyName'];
        $contactName=$row['contactName'];
        $eventTitle=$row['eventTitle'];
        //$phone=$row['phone'];
        $date=$row['date'];
        $status=$row['bstatus'];
        $booth=$row['boothAlias']

    ?>

   <tr><td style="color:#B2b2b2; padding-left:4px"><?php echo $id; ?></td><td><?php echo $contactName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $eventTitle; ?></td><td><?php echo $booth; ?></td><td><?php echo $date; ?></td><td><select name='status' id='status'>
        <option value='-1'>--Select--</option>
    <option value='0'>Approve</option>
    <option value='1'>Reject</option>
    <option value='2'>Pending</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    } //while
    ?>
</table>
```

And it return this:

[image: picture1]

I try to print out the record in the following pattern:

[image: picture2]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you move between picture 1 and picture 2 you can see that two Education Fair entries would be interpreted as Car Show entries.  You are mixing your model code with your display logic so be very careful that your ORDER BY matches your display code expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have all of your records ordered by `id` first, followed by `contactName` and then `eventTitle`, a simple conditional can check to see if the current records values match that of the previously displayed record, and if they do, omit them.  I've use ternary operators in this code just for the sake of compactness.

```
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {

    $date=$row['date'];
    $status=$row['bstatus'];

?>

<tr><td style="color:#B2b2b2; padding-left:4px"><?php echo ($id == $row['id']) ? "" : $row['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo ($contactName == $row['contactName']) ? "" : $row['contactName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($eventTitle== $row['eventTitle']) ? "" : $row['eventTitle']; ?></td><td><?php echo ($booth== $row['boothAlias']) ? "" : $row['boothAlias']; ?></td><td><?php echo $date; ?></td><td><select name='status' id='status'>
    <option value='-1'>--Select--</option>
<option value='0'>Approve</option>
<option value='1'>Reject</option>
<option value='2'>Pending</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<?php

    $id=$row['companyName'];
    $contactName=$row['contactName'];
    $eventTitle=$row['eventTitle'];
    //$phone=$row['phone'];
    $booth=$row['boothAlias'];

} //while
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved in PHP.

Just store contactName and eventTitle and do an if-statement to determine if you should declare `$contactName=$row['contactName'];` or `$contactName='';`

Answer (score 0):

I find your first picture way more informative and readable. 
Why do you want to make it worse and harder to read?